# Designing URLs without verbs for operations related to user in a REST API

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I'm building REST API.

I have following structure

```
GET /user/{id} - get
POST /users  - Create user
PUT /users/{id} - Update user
DELETE /users/{id} - Delete user
```

The problem is following. As I got from many tutorials/articles - it is bad practice to use action in URL. But what to do with such actions like:

**check email (is unique)**

**recover user by email**

?

Assume user registration. User submits form  ( POST /users ) and I need to check if email is unique. Do I need to do it in same api method and return validation errors as response body?

Or do I need to create something like

**POST /users/email**

And what about user recovering by email? Where do I need to do it? Because recover is verb

**POST /users/recover**

I'm not sure, that I'm doing it right and I can't find correct explanation for that situation.

Comment: What do you mean with *user recovering by email*? Please, provide some clarification and then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please note *recover* is a verb. So you can you the correspondent noun instead: *recovery*.

Answer (score 0):

### Validating the e-mail and registering the user

If you want, you can have an endpoint to check whether an e-mail is already registered or not. It's up to your requirements. So, you can have something as following and then send the e-mail which will be validated in the request payload:

```
POST /users/email/validation
{
    "email": "mail@example.com"
}
```

The endpoint above can be invoke, for example, when the user completes the e-mail field of your account registration form.

However, do not forget checking if the e-mail is already registered when creating a user:

```
POST /users
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "mail@example.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

If an e-mail is already registered, you could consider returning a [`409 Conflict`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code and a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.

### Recovering the password

I'm unsure if this is your requirement, because of this I posted a comment asking for clarification. I presume you are trying to recover the password of a user, assuming the user has no more access to their account.

If so, you could have an endpoint as following and then send the e-mail of the user in the request payload:

```
POST /users/password/recovery
{
    "email": "mail@example.com"
}
```

Then your server can send a link with a token to the e-mail specified in the payload. Only send the e-mail if the e-mail specified in the payload is registered in your application, of course.

The link should take the user to a page where they will enter the new password and, when submitting, an endpoint to replace the password of the user will be invoked, sending the token and the new password to the server:

```
PUT /users/password?token=SomeValueGoesHere
{
    "password": "654321"
}
```

Comment: Regarding to the REST principles, using /users/email/validation is incorrect. email is not resource. It is just field of user

Comment: @Ahmed The `email` can be considered a subresource of the `user` resource. So, that's correct. Anyways, you can change from `/users/email/validation` to `/users/validation/email`.

Comment: @Ahmed According to Roy T. Fielding, the REST Godfather, *[any information that can be named can be a resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)*.